# Anyway to have programs share Windows Explorer icon overlays?

Tags: windows, tortoisesvn, overlay

The fact that Windows only allows 15 icon overlays is well worn territory at this point. I understand how to rename the registry entries to get the overlays I absolutely *need* to be visible. But I wonder if there is a better way.

I don't know much about registry editing and I know next to nothing about the inner working of windows and how the overlays actually get requested/delivered. So I'm not sure how these overlays actually work... But the programs I use that have overlays (TortoiseSvn, Box, Google Drive) all do basically the same thing. Generally speaking, they compare the status of a file locally to the status of a file in the cloud or on a server. For this reason it seems like many of these overlays could logically be shared. Why couldn't the BoxSynced, GoogleDriveSynced, and Tortoise1Normal all use the same icon?

So my question is: Does anyone know of a way to manipulate the registry to combine some icon overlays? Or is there maybe a some sort of tool or utility out there that can achieve something like a set of "shared overlays"?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this by just modifying the registry, but possibly with a small utility. (I think, if it was higher priority it could field overlay requests from the system, and then send them on to other overlay handlers, reporting back appropriately. A GUI could allow mapping overlays from multiple programs to a single icon.) If you modify your question to include other types of solutions, then I'll add a bounty.

Comment: I edited the question. The edits I made were fairly minor and not as specific as your comment. I'm new here so still trying to get the hang of the best way of formatting this kind of question. If you feel I should make additional edits let me know. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TortoiseOverlays is a shim that can serve this purpose. It was designed to share icon overlays across Tortoise clients (SVN, git, Hg), but it can be repurposed to do the same for file syncing programs as long as you can match up File Syncing states to one of the given Version Control icons (it would be nice if TortoiseOverlays was extend it to allow for more possible icons).

Instructions:

1. Install TortoiseOverlays. It can be installed [directly](https://sourceforge.net/p/tortoisesvn/code/HEAD/tree/TortoiseOverlays/version-1.1.4/bin/) or it comes with the Tortoise clients.
2. Make sure the TortoiseXxxxx keys come first in [HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers] by prepeding a few more spaces.
3. Add appropriate keys to [HKLM\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays] to determine the mapping.

You can add the appropriate keys by reading the [TortoiseOverlays instructions](https://tortoisesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/TortoiseOverlays/Documentation.txt) and then figuring out which states are mapped to from the overlay keys (this is usually easy given the key names, but for Dropbox and OneDrive see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/809529/) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1037648/) ). Below I have worked out an example that works for me for Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, and OwnCloud. One can save the appropriate sections to a .reg file and import them.

```
    ; GoogleDriveSynced
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Normal]
    "GoogleDrive"="{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D40}"

    ; GoogleDriveBlacklisted
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Ignored]
    "GoogleDrive"="{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D42}"

    ; GoogleDriveSyncing
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Modified]
    "GoogleDrive"="{81539FE6-33C7-4CE7-90C7-1C7B8F2F2D41}"

    ;OCError
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Conflict]
    "OC"="{0960F090-F328-48A3-B746-276B1E3C3722}"

    ;OCErrorShared
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Conflict]
    "OCShared"="{0960F091-F328-48A3-B746-276B1E3C3722}"

    ;OCOK
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Normal]
    "OC"="{0960F092-F328-48A3-B746-276B1E3C3722}"

    ;OCOKShared
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Normal]
    "OCShared"="{0960F093-F328-48A3-B746-276B1E3C3722}"

    ;OCSync
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Modified]
    "OC"="{0960F094-F328-48A3-B746-276B1E3C3722}"

    ;OCSyncShared
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Modified]
    "OCShared"="{0960F095-F328-48A3-B746-276B1E3C3722}"

    ;OCWarning
    ;"OC"="{0960F096-F328-48A3-B746-276B1E3C3722}"

    ;OCWarningShared
    ;"OCShared"="{0960F097-F328-48A3-B746-276B1E3C3722}"

    ;DropboxExt1 - "Synced!"
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Normal]
    "Dropbox"="{FB314ED9-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    ;DropboxExt2 - "Sync in progress"
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Modified]
    "Dropbox"="{FB314EDA-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    ;DropboxExt3 - "Synced! - Locked"
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Normal]
    "DropboxLock"="{FB314EDD-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    ;DropboxExt4 - "Sync in progress - Locked"
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Modified]
    "DropboxLock"="{FB314EDE-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    ;DropboxExt5 - "Sync not happening" (red x)
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Conflict]
    "Dropbox"="{FB314EDB-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    ;DropboxExt6 - "Sync not happening - Locked" (red x + Lock)
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Conflict]
    "DropboxLock"="{FB314EDF-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    ;DropboxExt7 - "A file or folder isn't syncing" (gray minus)
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Ignored]
    "Dropbox"="{FB314EDC-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    ;DropboxExt8 - "A file or folder isn't syncing - Locked" (gray minus+Lock)
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Ignored]
    "DropboxLock"="{FB314EE0-A251-47B7-93E1-CDD82E34AF8B}"

    ;OneDrive1 - "Not syncing" (red x)
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Conflict]
    "OneDrive"="{BBACC218-34EA-4666-9D7A-C78F2274A524}"

    ;OneDrive2 - "Synced (Shared)"
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Normal]
    "OneDriveShared"="{5AB7172C-9C11-405C-8DD5-AF20F3606282}"

    ;OneDrive3 - "Syncing (Shared)"
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Modified]
    "OneDriveShared"="{A78ED123-AB77-406B-9962-2A5D9D2F7F30}"

    ;OneDrive4 - "Synced"
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Normal]
    "OneDrive"="{F241C880-6982-4CE5-8CF7-7085BA96DA5A}"

    ;OneDrive5 - "Syncing"
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Modified]
    "OneDrive"="{A0396A93-DC06-4AEF-BEE9-95FFCCAEF20E}"

    ;BoxSyncSynced
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Normal]
    "BoxSync"="{c89f9943-8f58-3eca-bd55-a658f53b2f48}"

    ;BoxSyncNotSynced
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Modified]
    "BoxSync"="{5ea95e3d-3e46-3812-b03c-49785fa67d41}"

    ;BoxSyncFileLocked
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Locked]
    "BoxSync"="{2a607da5-abe8-358e-a881-c0f5faf2d3a5}"

    ;BoxSyncFileLockedByOther
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Modified]
    "BoxSync"="{f7d2951f-0b6b-346c-99ec-69cffc30a364}

    ;BoxSyncProblem
    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\TortoiseOverlays\Conflict]
    "BoxSync"="{a88b7184-bfa1-3d14-8efb-2225df9699bc}"
```

A few caveats for my worked out registry keys:

- I have mapped "Error" to "Conflict" and "Syncing" to "Modified". There was no obvious match for OwnCloud's "Warnings" so they are not mapped to anything.
- Many programs have additional icons that differ from the main ones by a characteristic that I ignore, so that I map both in the pair to the same icon. These include OwnCloud "shared", Dropbox "locked", and OneDrive "shared" pairs.
- The keys depend on CLSIDs which may change between versions of file syncing programs.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Since tortoise was already installed all I had to do was the registry edits. Should I edit your answer to add the BoxSync-specific keys?